# Powershell $button.add_click executes the whole code inside the add_click block

Tags: wpf, powershell, event-handling

I am new to WPF and event-handling using powershell, what I want to achieve is on click of a button, the progress bar should be shown from 0-100. But when I am running the following piece of code, it computes the whole code inside the add_click block and it only shows the last iteration in the loop.
I know maybe it is a silly solution, but I do need some help in this.

```
$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)

$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({   
    $XamlPath="C:\Forms\MyFormsv1.xaml" 
    $inputXML = Get-Content -Path $XamlPath
    [xml]$Global:xmlWPF = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"','' -replace "x:N",'N'  -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'

    #Add WPF and Windows Forms assemblies
    try{
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework,WindowsBase,system.windows.forms
    } catch {
    Throw “Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework assemblies.”
    }


    $syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((new-object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xmlWPF))

    [xml]$XAML = $xmlWPF

    $xmlWPF.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | %{
    $Global:synchash.Add($_.Name,$synchash.Window.FindName($_.Name) )}

    function tool1_progress{
        $var1=50
        for($index=1 ; $index -le $var1; $index++)
        {            
            [int]$tmpProgNum= ($index/$var1) * 100
            $syncHash.tool1_pb.Value= $tmpProgNum
            $syncHash.consoleOutput.Text=$index
            Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250 
        }
    }
    $syncHash.myButton.add_click({tool1_progress})  
    $syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | out-null      
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

> $tool1 is a label. $tool1_pb is a progress bar. $consoleOutput is a
>   text box.

Comment: Your code runs on the same thread that updates the UI which means that the UI cannot be updated while your loop executes.

Comment: Yeah I know there must be some sort of threading issue, can you provide me a solution on how to take care of this issue. Thanks though. :)

Comment: You need to create a new runspace using `BeginInvoke()` .  This helped me when I was trying to do the same thing as you. https://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/

Comment: Even I am not a powershell guy, but yet pertaining to requirements I have to code in powershell, I know the C# alternative, dispatcher and stuff, in powershell it's actually Start-Job or something, working on that. :(

Comment: In Powershell Studio GUI applications it works to add `[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::DoEvents()` in the loop to update the form during the loop. Have never written WPF GUI's from scratch so dont know if it also applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I integrate WPF and PowerShell all the time. [This](https://learn-powershell.net/2012/10/14/powershell-and-wpf-writing-data-to-a-ui-from-a-different-runspace/) website helped me immensely. You can't update a UI that's running on the same thread, so you need to invoke a new runspace using `BeginInvoke()`

```
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({   
$Global:uiHash.Error = $Error
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework,PresentationCore,WindowsBase
$xaml = @"YOURXAMLHERE"
$Global:uiHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($xaml )

[xml]$XAML = $xaml
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | %{
    $Global:uihash.Add($_.Name,$uihash.Window.FindName($_.Name) )}
$Global:uiHash.Window.ShowDialog() | out-null
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$handle = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

Then to update whatever it is you need, you would use `Window.Dispatcher.Invoke`

```
$Global:uiHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$Global:uiHash.Window.Title = "MyWindowTitle"},"Normal")
```

EDIT

```
$Global:uiHash.Button1.Add_Click(tool1_progress)
```

EDIT

Throw in your XML and this will work. You have to create another runspace on top of the other in order to keep updating the textbox and progress bar. Note that `synchash` MUST be `$Global:synchash`. Functions courtesy of [this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40976416/multiple-functions-in-wpf-gui-from-runspaces)

```
$Global:syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash",$syncHash)

$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({   
$XamlPath="C:\Forms\MyFormsv1.xaml" 
$inputXML = @"YOURXMLHERE"@
[xml]$Global:xmlWPF = $inputXML 

#Add WPF and Windows Forms assemblies
try{
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework,WindowsBase,system.windows.forms
} catch {
Throw “Failed to load Windows Presentation Framework assemblies.”
}


$Global:syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load((new-object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xmlWPF))

[xml]$XAML = $xmlWPF

$xmlWPF.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]") | %{
$Global:synchash.Add($_.Name,$Global:syncHash.Window.FindName($_.Name) )}

function Start-Runspace{
param($scriptblock)
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"         
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("SyncHash",$global:synchash)
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript($ScriptBlock)
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$psCMD.BeginInvoke()
}

   $SB = { 
    $var1=50
    for($index=1 ; $index -le $var1; $index++)
    {            
        [int]$tmpProgNum= ($index/$var1) * 100
        $Global:syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$Global:Synchash.tool1_pb.value = "$tmpprognum"},"Normal")
        $Global:syncHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke([action]{$Global:Synchash.consoleoutput.text = "$index"},"Normal")
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 250 

    }

}


$Global:syncHash.myButton.add_click({Start-Runspace $SB})  
$Global:syncHash.Window.ShowDialog() | out-null      
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$data = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
start-sleep -Milliseconds 300
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, I was actually going through the website you suggested, will try to implement the changes and see how to make it work. :)

Comment: Awesome, if you run into any issues, let me know. WPF & PS can be a nightmare to get working together properly!

Comment: Hi Nick, 
Ran into another issue, for changing things in the UI we are using that "uiHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke", but where am I supposed to place the $uiHash.button.add_click event? I tried placing along with this script, still running into the same issue that's because it's again part of the same thread. What am I supposed to do ? Help please.

Comment: I’m a bit confused as to what you’re asking, but I updated the post as to how you would use a click. If that doesn’t work, here's another good website that I refer to frequently for click events: https://smsagent.wordpress.com/2015/09/07/powershell-tip-utilizing-runspaces-for-responsive-wpf-gui-applications/ . Or, if you could edit your post to show the new code, I can try and work off of that.

Comment: Please view the updated code and tell what changes need to be done to make it work, thanks.

Comment: I edited the post again, take a look and let me know. :)

Comment: Finally its working, thanks a lot, actually now I am understanding how to deal with runspaces and stuff. Thanks again!! .. :)